# How to use *ngFor in angular 2 bootstrap modal

Tags: angular, bootstrap-modal

I am trying to bind data to my modal using *ngFor in angular 2 but not able to view any data in modal when in my component data is available.

**modal.component.html**

```
 <div class="modal modalscroll" tabindex="-1" role="dialog"  [ngStyle]="{'display':addSplitBilling}">
    <div class="modal-dialog splitBillingModal">
    <form>
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true" (click) = "clearSplitBilling()">×</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Split Billing</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="container"></div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <table>
                <tbody>
                    <tr *ngFor="let d of data.dupStmtAddresses; let i = index">
                          <td>{{d.addressee}}</td>
                          <td>{{d.splitPercent}}</td>
                      </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
        </div>

      </div>
    </form>
    </div>
  </div>
```

**modal.component.ts**

```
export class DupStatementsComponent implements OnInit {
    addSplitBilling = 'none';
    data: any;

    ngOnInit() {
        this.getData();
    }


    getData(){
        this.duplicateStatementsProvider.getDuplicateStatements()
        .subscribe(
            data => {
                this.data = JSON.parse(data['_body']);
            },
            error => {
            }
        );
    }


    splitBilling(){
        console.log(this.data.dupStmtAddresses);
        this.addSplitBilling = 'block';
    }
}
```

In console I can see that data is available but in modal not able to view any data.

[image: Here is what I am getting in console]

In data i am getting this response from web service -->

```
{"createdDate":"2017-12-04T17:04:00.174+05:30","id":1,"dupStmtAddresses":[{"createdDate":null,"id":1,"addressee":"a","address1":"a","address2":"a","address3":"a","address4":"a","email":"a","splitPercent":null,"new":false},{"createdDate":null,"id":2,"addressee":"b","address1":"b","address2":"b","address3":"b","address4":"b","email":"b","splitPercent":null,"new":false},{"createdDate":null,"id":3,"addressee":"c","address1":"c","address2":"c","address3":"c","address4":"c","email":"c","splitPercent":null,"new":false}],"enableSplitBilling":true,"new":false}
```

I have no idea why it is not working.

Comment: can you reproduce this using a `plunkr` or a `stackblitz`. how this modal is opened

Comment: can you show how the data looks in console ? and if you get any error in console ?

Comment: In console i am able to view array of objects

Comment: I have added an image what i am getting in console

Comment: could you print the length of array data.dupStmtAddresses using interpolation inside modal {{data.dupStmtAddresses.length}} to see if the data is accessible in modal. That would be helpful in debugging!

Comment: I tried to print the length but it is not displaying anything ... even i tried with data only it is also not visible

Comment: In snapshot above have you logged data? Then why are you using data.dupStmtAddresses when the content is directly in data and not in any property?

Comment: @Aakriti define `data: any=[]` and inside function `this.data = [JSON.parse(data['_body'])];` (array of object) ,check that if it works.

Comment: no data is not an array .. ok i will share the response that i am getting in data

Comment: Here in data there is a field 'dupStmtAddresses' which is an array of objects

Comment: @VishalGulati the content i am trying to use is in a field of data that's why i am using data.dupStmtAddress ... it should return an array and i am trying to get those values using *ngfor

Comment: onInit i am calling that getdata function and onclick of a button i am opening this modal using splitBilling function

Comment: @Aakriti check this https://plnkr.co/edit/09nDftBCauAlKpt5Auj9?p=preview

Comment: @Patata thanks for your help .. i have got my issue

Comment: @Aakriti Does this solves your issue. I am new to angular.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160590/discussion-between-aakriti-and-patata).

Answer (score 1):

What I can conclude from your description and comments above is that, the service is yet to respond before the modal template is created. I am not sure if it will work but could you please try:

Instead of using data directly in modal, use a new variable modalContent initialised to null/empty string. On click of button to open modal, assign the data to modalContent variable and use this in `ngFor` loop.

```
export class DupStatementsComponent implements OnInit {
    modalContent: any = '';
    //... same as your logic

    splitBilling(){
        console.log(this.data.dupStmtAddresses);
        this.modalContent = this.data.dupStmtAddresses;
        this.addSplitBilling = 'block';
    }
}
```

your ngFor loop:

```
<tr *ngFor="let d of modalContent; let i = index">
```

Kindly share if it works!

Comment: Thanks for your response but i have tried it .. its not working.. even i have tried with dummy data instead of using service but not able to view that in modal

Comment: I created a plunk for this with dummy data it's working fine there.. its really weird why it is not working in my app .. Here is the link for that .. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-flo8mr

Comment: :) It should work in real app as well.. Can you try there?

Comment: looks like something is blocking that data in modal .. ok thanks for your help ..  will try to figure it out .. thanks again

Comment: WC! Cheers. If you find the issue, do share as it may be helpful for someone else.